# Pause loop on user input

Tags: java, multithreading, loops

If I have a loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) { 
    System.out.println("Hello, User " + i;
    Thread.sleep(1000)
}
```

How would I go about adding code that did not *require* user input, but if the user chose the pause the loop at a given point, they could do so, and resume a few moments later?

Comment: What? You're saying you don't want user input, but then describe user input. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm with @tnw - your intentions are not clear. Do you want to hard-code a longer break for your `i=6` step?

Comment: It's not in the code yet because I don't know if it's possible. I don't want it to ask every iteration if the user wants to type something, I want the user to be able to type something at any point in each iteration to hard pause it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this , you'll need to implement multi-threading. One thread will run the loop(T1) while other can wait for the user input(T2).

> T1 - while --> check if input through common bool attribute -->
> continue/break loop
>
> T2 - wait for input --> if input=="pause" --> set common attribute to true to
> pause loop

Something like :

```
class MultiThread implements Runnable {

    boolean gotInput = false;
    int i = 0;
    public void run() {
        for(;i <= 10 && !gotInput; i++) {
            System.out.println("Hello, User " + i;
            Thread.sleep(1000)
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        MultiThread mt = new MultiThread ();
        Thread t = new Thread(mt);
        t.start();

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!s.next().equals("pause"));

        test.gotInput = true;
    }
}
```

On the same lines you can resume the code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a background thread that waits 1 second for the user to select pause. If it is not selected within that 1 second, move forward.

The way this is written, your `Thread.sleep()` will lock up the UI for 1 second, and regardless of what the user does it won't affect your program.